# Pycharm does no read python file without error

Tags: python, pycharm

When I create a project and I run the script which should print something but I got nothing:

```
C:\Users\mahfo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe C:/Users/mahfo/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/main.py

Process finished with exit code 0
```

`main.py` file content:

```py
print('wef')
def print_hi(name):
    # Use a breakpoint in the code line below to debug your script.
    print(f'Hi, {name}')  # Press Ctrl+F8 to toggle the breakpoint.
    

# Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_hi('PyCharm')
```

When I check: `sys.prefix == sys.base_prefix`, output is: `True`,
and `sys.prefix` output:
`'C:\\Users\\mahfo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32'`

It is the first time I try on Windows. Do you know why this happens, please? Any help is appreciated.

Edit:

I've tried to run the file directly from the command prompt and it run correctly with python but not python3. So Pycharm does not recognize the file (without error) because the file can be read only with python2. I don't understand why because the pycharm environment setting are on python3.

Edit 2:

I had Python 2.7 installed that i have deleted.
Pycharm is still not printing when I run but it print on debug console. I really don't understand why.

Comment: what does `main.py` contain?

Comment: @FlyingTeller I have edited

Comment: the path to your python main file is using **forward** slashes... try **backward** slashes.... "C:\Users\mahfo\PycharmProjects\....\main.py"

Comment: @caldweln It is already backward under pycharm config. I don't know why it print with forward slash

Comment: It appears to me that there is something wrong with your system's configuration, or you aren't telling us everything.  If you are running the Python script you've shown us using the command you show us, Python should always print something to the console.  That first `print` statement should output `wef` for any version of Python.  If you just run `C:\Users\mahfo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe`, do you get the Python help message?